# Is the leptokurtic distribution always time varying and what will the impact be on a weak stationary time series

Tags: distributions, stationarity, kurtosis

I hope this alteration will make more sense.

A normal distribution is defined by its first and second moment. When these are finite, as in the case of weak stationarity, then the weak stationarity will also imply strict stationarity, as the distribution will be the same for all time periods.

However shouldn't this also apply for a leptokurtic distribution, as long as it is symmetric along the mean?

Can the leptokurtic distribution only be present in a time varying sequence as the outliers of the distribution are very extreme compared to a normal distribution, and then this naturally imply a time varying distribution?

Comment: Your statement "For strict stationarity we always assume normal distribution" is incorrect. You should review the definition of strict stationarity and probably the definition of weak stationarity as well.

Comment: You're right I got that wrong. I meant why a weak stationary process strictly stationary when the distribution is normal. How can't that be for a letokurtic distribution. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I hope the above alterations makes the question a bit clearer.

Comment: Weak stationarity implies strict stationarity only when all marginals are normal **and** when all $n$-variate distributions are multi-Normal for all $n\ge 1.$  What do you mean by "the" leptokurtic distribution?  That's like writing about "the" tall man or "the" large rock: it's too indefinite to be meaningful.

Comment: I mean a (instead of the) distribution with a kurtosis in excess of 3.

Comment: Intuitively I wouldn't think that a leptokurtic distribution would have anything to do with the process being time variant, as the extreme outliers and realisations near the mean could just be alternating.

Comment: I think some clarifications are in order:  Which distribution are you referring to? The marginal (integrated over time) distribution?  Or the time-specific conditionals? It's a very important distinction, because the former can be highly kurtotic, even when the latter are purely Gaussian. This can happen, eg, under conditional heteroscedasticity.